# Make a div unable to get focus (like toolbar buttons)

Tags: javascript, focus, toolbar

Is there a way to make a div unable to get focus? This is the normal behavior of toolbar buttons.

Let's say the focus is on a text input. A click on a div should not make it the case that the focus of the text input is lost.

Here is a basic setup:

html:

```
<div id="toolbar-button">
    Button
</div>
<input id="input">
```

I tried to stick a refocus on the div's `mousedown` event but it do
es not work:

```
document.getElementById('toolbar-button').addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
    document.getElementById('input').focus();
})
```

Using a `click` event is getting back the focus on click but then the focus is still lost while a mouse button is only down (and also that a click event will happen afterwards is not granted).

Here is a pen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxjPva

I know that one can make elements not receive focus on tab by setting `tabindex = "-1"`. But this does not work for mouse events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line to your listener:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

It will prevent focus to be set on the button, the default action when the button is pressed.

Comment: Great. That seems to work. I guess then styling of the button has to be done via javascript since css events like `:active` won't work.

Comment: Well, I'd probably recommend that you use a button for setting the focus to the text field instead of a div if you want button styles, and using a label, which automatically sets focus on the input if clicked on, see the updated Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZpXqK

Comment: That doesn't work. The focus is lost when mouse button is pressed on the button and without releasing it moved away from the button and released outside.

Comment: I want to keep the focus on the input independent on how the button is touched. Just like toolbar buttons work in normal applications. Take, for example, a writer application. If the focus is on the text, then no matter how you touch the "bold-button" the text will not lose focus.

Comment: Try adding in the event listener again, with `event.preventDefault()`, on the button, that should do the trick!

Comment: Sure. But then styling wise that brings me back to square one since the button does not get pressed anymore. I will just do the styling via javascript as suggested before.